# Scrooge McDuck space adventure where he fights an alien despot from an energy oriented economy

Tags: story-identification, comics, donald-duck

This comic book was published in Spain between 1976 and 1980 and was probably a work of Disney's Italian studio. Might be a work by Romano Scarpa.

There is a planet where energy has replaced money. People (anthropomorphic ducks, of course) who can't pay their taxes are forced to generate energy on big wheels. The planetary *ducktator* owns a "Money Bin" with a huge amount of giant cylindrical batteries similar to AAA pocket batteries.

He learns that there is a duck on Earth as rich as he is and sends a challenge to Uncle Scrooge. Their spaceships meet in space and blast each other with energy. Scrooge has a boiler in his ship that converts money into energy. Eventually, Scrooge wins the battle by adding to the money in the boiler plans for humanitarian aid to underdeveloped nations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple failed searches [*], I think I found it. It should be [*"Zio Paperone e il "botto" siderale"*](https://inducks.org/story.php?c=I+TL++856-C). It is a story drawn by Giorgio Cavazzano (whose career started inking Romano Scarpa's pencils, so you were not completely wrong!) in 1972, and re-printed in Spain as *"Tío Gilito y el "reto" sideral"* in 1977.

The description on the inducks page reads:

> An extra-terrestial learns that he might not be the richest person in universe, because of Scrooge.

[image]

[image]

---

[*]

I first tried to search in the [stories drawn by Romano Scarpa](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fumetti_Disney_di_Romano_Scarpa), founding nothing matching the description.

Then I tried the inducks search for [stories between 1975 and 1981 reprinted in Spain](https://inducks.org/comp2.php?code=&keyw=&keywt=i&exactpg=&pg1=&pg2=&bro2=&bro3=&exactparts=&parts1=&parts2=&kind=0&rowsperpage=0&columnsperpage=0&hero=scrooge&xapp=&univ=&xa2=&creat=&creat2=&plot=&plot2=&writ=&writ2=&art=&art2=&ink=&ink2=&excludeCZ=on&excludeUseDifferentCode=on&pub1=1975&pub2=1981&zes=on&ser=&xref=&mref=&xrefd=&repabb=&repabbc=al&reppub1=&reppub2=&imgmode=0&vdesc2=on&vdesc=en&sort1=auto).

Finally I realized that if it was *reprinted* between 1975 and 1981 it could have been first printed some years before, so I searched for [stories between 1970 and 1975 reprinted in Spain](https://inducks.org/comp2.php?code=&keyw=&keywt=i&exactpg=&pg1=&pg2=&bro2=&bro3=&exactparts=&parts1=&parts2=&kind=0&rowsperpage=0&columnsperpage=0&hero=scrooge&xapp=&univ=&xa2=&creat=&creat2=&plot=&plot2=&writ=&writ2=&art=&art2=&ink=&ink2=&excludeCZ=on&excludeUseDifferentCode=on&pub1=1970&pub2=1975&zes=on&ser=&xref=&mref=&xrefd=&repabb=&repabbc=al&reppub1=&reppub2=&imgmode=0&vdesc2=on&vdesc=en&sort1=auto).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a couple of pages. Poor people forced to operate a wheel to pay off their debts. Scrooge pouring money into his electricity generator.

Comment: Good job. Thanks a lot.